# How to get rid of Variable API in PyTorch.autograd?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am forwarding, and backpropping tensor data `X` through two simple nn.Module PyTorch models instances, `model1` and `model2`.

I can't get this process to work without usage of the [depreciated `Variable` API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html).

**So this works just fine:**

```
    y1 = model1(X)
    v = Variable(y1.data, requires_grad=training)         # Its all about this line!
    y2 = model2(v)
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    loss = criterion(y2, y)
    loss.backward()
    y1.backward(v.grad)
    self.step()
```

**But this will throw an error:**

```
    y1 = model1(X)
    y2 = model2(y1)
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    loss = criterion(y2, y)
    loss.backward()
    y1.backward(y1.grad) # it breaks here
    self.step()
>>> RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

I just can't seem to find a relevant difference between `v` in the first implementation, and `y1` in the second. In both cases `requires_grad` is set to `True`. The only thing I could find was that `y1.grad_fn=<ThnnConv2DBackward>` and `v.grad_fn=<ThnnConv2DBackward>`

What am I missing here? **What (tensor attributes?) do I not know about, and if `Variable` is depreciated, what other implementation would work?**

Comment: While I cannot see your full code (the definition of `model1` or the Class self belongs to), are you sure it is not just a typo? In the first you write `y1.backward(v.grad)`, in the second `y1.backward(y1.grad)`. Notice the `y1`

Comment: There's no typo in the models, they're a single layer nn.Module instance. I'm not getting what you think the typo would be in your second line

Comment: `y1.backward(y1.grad.data)` in the second case does not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I came to the following two solutions.
The solution provided elsewhere in this thread retained the computation graph manually, without an option the free them, thus running fine initially, but causing OOM errors later on.

The first solution is to tie the models together using the built in `torch.nn.Sequential` as such:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(Model1(), Model2())
```

it's as easy as that. It looks clean and behaves exactly like an ordinary model would.

The alternative is to simply tie them together manually:

```
        model1 = Model1()
        model2 = Model2()
        y1 = model1(X)
        y2 = model2(y1)
        loss = criterion(y2, y)
        loss.backward()
```

My fear that this would only backpropagate `model2` turned out to be unsubstantiated, since `model1` is also stored in the computation graph that is back propagated over.
This implementation enabled inceased transparancy of the interface between the two models, compared to the previous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]
You are not correctly passing the `y1.grad` into `y1.backward` in the second example. After the first `backward` all the intermediate gradient will be destroyed, you need a special hook to extract that gradients. And in your case you are passing the `None` value. Here is small example to reproduce your case:

Code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


torch.manual_seed(42)


class Model1(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return x.pow(3)


class Model2(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return x / 2


model1 = Model1()
model2 = Model2()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

X = torch.randn(1, 5, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.randn(1, 5)

y1 = model1(X)
y2 = model2(y1)

loss = criterion(y2, y)
# We are going to backprop 2 times, so we need to 
# retain_graph=True while first backward
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

try:
    y1.backward(y1.grad)
except RuntimeError as err:
    print(err)
    print('y1.grad: ', y1.grad)
```

Output:

```py
grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
y1.grad:  None
```

So you need to extract them correctly:

Code:

```py
def extract(V):
    """Gradient extractor.
    """
    def hook(grad):
        V.grad = grad
    return hook


model1 = Model1()
model2 = Model2()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

X = torch.randn(1, 5, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.randn(1, 5)

y1 = model1(X)
y2 = model2(y1)

loss = criterion(y2, y)
y1.register_hook(extract(y1))
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

print('y1.grad', y1.grad)

y1.backward(y1.grad)
```

Output:

```py
y1.grad:  tensor([[-0.1763, -0.2114, -0.0266, -0.3293,  0.0534]])
```

Comment: I had some trouble understanding your answer, but both `y1` and `v` are multidimensional tensors of the same shape, while one works and the other doesn't, so how would reduction solve the problem?

Comment: Oh, I see, you are passing None in 2nd case. I updated the answer.

Comment: I am not sure why it works with Variable, but it is not recommended to use it, and you are passing y1.data, not y1 with all the gradients, so am not sure again in such approach, it may cause that your gradients are not accumulated correctly in this case

Comment: In addition, the solution presented causes OOM errors (due to the computation graph being retained). Using `Variable` to free this graph was actually advised my PyTorch mods, about a year ago https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-free-computation-graph-of-arbitrary-part/14756 .

Comment: I checked that answer from discuss.. and yeah, I am a little bit surprised, that there is no other "pragmatic" way how to do that :( PS. You didn't provide any additional code, so It was hard to imagine the complexity of your models.

Comment: Would knowing model complexity have helped? Any model complexity with memory leakage and limited memory will eventually cause OOM errors.